# Changing Notification icons dynamically

Tags: android

I want the `Notification` icon to be a number that can be anywhere from 1 to 1000 depending on conditions.

Is there a way to do this dynamically (e.g. generate an `Icon` from a `String` and use it in `setSmallIcon()`) without manually creating all these numbers as an image file and calling them dynamically?

Comment: You might want to look into badging instead

Comment: Not possible under API level 23.

Comment: @GabeSechan can you please give a specific example? Tried looking for bading but I'm getting a lot of htis, the ones I looked into doesn't seem to be the ones I need. I'm trying to create something similar to [this](https://lh4.ggpht.com/9PZYdDwGmFliEq1OKrM_PU1NId5q1uYleGittsMyNHwMn6JQd2hvu-cTrqsS00phew=h310-rw)

Comment: @user13 can you kindly elaborate? How can we do it in API 23 above?

Comment: @KarlJamoralin see my answer below.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there is no way (i'm aware of) to do this below API level 23.

**On API level 23+**:

You could use `Canvas.drawText()` to create a `Bitmap` from your `String`.

For example:

```
public Bitmap createBitmapFromString(String string) {
    Paint paint = new Paint();
    paint.setAntiAlias(true);
    paint.setTextSize(50); // size is in pixels

    Rect textBounds = new Rect();
    paint.getTextBounds(string, 0, string.length(), textBounds);

    Bitmap bitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(textBounds.width(), textBounds.height(),
        Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);

    Canvas canvas = new Canvas(bitmap);
    canvas.drawText(string, -textBounds.left,
        textBounds.height() - textBounds.bottom, paint);

    return bitmap;
}
```

After that you could create an `Icon` using this `Bitmap` with `Icon.createWithBitmap()`.

(this method was added in API level 23)

And then pass this `Icon` to `setSmallIcon()`.

(`setSmallIcon(Icon icon)` was also added in API level 23)

Comment: what to do below API 23 ??